# What purpose must an answer serve?

Tags: discussion, answers

When reading some [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647331/how-to-swap-two-numbers-without-using-temp-variables-or-arithmetic-operations/#answer-3647423) containing arguments about an answer not being entirely as *"expected"* or *"should have been"* (to those who wrote the comments), I started to wonder myself and I could not have found any rule to this.

The comment contained the following:

> ...But I "gave him what he needs not what he wants" and as such he should become a better developer for it...

[image]

What purpose must answers on Stack Overflow serve? Is there actually a purpose an answer must serve?

I read the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

> Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful...

It is nowhere stated what an answer's purpose would require for as far as I can tell.

Would an answer provided rather contain information that serves the OP's *requirements* (needs) or OP's *desires* (wants)?

I personally think there is a difference between these two, as the answer could provide as much information to let OP play with whatever information has been provided **or** the answer could contain anything related to the subject and more, which in turn would validate the following:

> but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.

Would it be wrong thinking for a Stack Overflow user to "just only" provide whatever OP would require/need in an answer rather than a full clarification?

For those who think this question might be related to being a clone of "Should an answer contain a rhetorical question", that's not the point. The answer provided as per example could've been shaped differently without it being a rhetorical question and still, my question would stand.

Comment: For as far as I can tell, the question I am trying to ask here has nothing to do with the fact a rhetorical question has ben asked in an answer (other than the given example containing such, but not being the point).

Comment: Well that an old question 2010-2011 and answers and rules have change a bit with time. But

The answer is correct, and it answers the question no arithmetic operation are used. From every word in the question and in Op's comment , I don't find OP that it was not what OP wanted. In fact commented Xor answer that 
 it was not what he wanted. 
Every other answer used Temp variable or arithmetic operation that is forbidden in the question it self.

Comment: Try to fully explain (or as much as you can). I almost exclusively answer questions from new users and will support them till they've solved their problem, even if the question has down votes. This is because a few years ago I had another account with almost 1.2k reputation and I ended up deleting it because at the time Stack Overflow was (IMO) very hostile towards new users. Instead of being helped simple/easy questions would often be met with *"do it yourself"*, *"google it"* or slapped with duplicate/close/down votes. Stack Overflow has since changed and become much (***much***) friendlier.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Would it be wrong thinking for a Stack Overflow user to "just only" provide whatever OP would require/need in an answer rather than a full clarification?

Yes. Assume the OP doesn't know what they're doing, and assume that the constraints they mention (if any) are out of ignorance, not out of reality.

To go to the idiomatic idiotic example:

> **Q**: How can I hammer a nail into the wall with a shoe?

Can be answered by:

> **A**: Very slowly.

The answer is definitely correct. Given enough patience and a thick enough sole, one can hammer a nail into a wall with a shoe.

A better answer is:

> **A**: Shoes aren't the best for hammering nails into walls. Sure, you can do it if you do it slowly, but you'd better use a bottle, they're sturdier.

It mentions the problems with the OP's constraints, and offers an alternative. Ultimately a sane soul will come along:

> **A**: Forget about nails, shoes and bottles. After endless back-and-forth in comments under your question we found out that you want to hang a painting on a drywall wall. Use an electric drill to drill a hole, put an drywall anchor in there and screw a screw into it to hang your painting on.

There are enough people who know how to answer with the first answer. We don't have enough people who do the last.

The ultimate answer analyzes the OP's problem, points out any flaws with their reasoning and offers more viable alternatives.

And sure, there are questions where the OP lives in a world where only nails and shoes exist (i.e. legacy code, obnoxious lead developers, absurd coding guidelines), but then still *"You should not do this; do that instead"* is a valid answer - if not for the OP, then for later visitors.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that we often get XY problems, where askers want to know how to do perform a solution, without actually telling us the core problem, which often leads to a completely different answer.  Knowing how to surface that is often a very unappreciated skill.

Comment: @fbueckert indeed, oh how often do you get a request how to safely drill a hole in one's skull when the simple answer would have been a painkiller, because the source problem is a head ache...

Comment: @Gimby Don't knock skull holes!  [Trepanning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trepanning) is an art form.  A little old and outdated, but takes real skill to perform properly. :P  Likely overkill for what ails you, but solves the problem by giving you a host of new ones.